# Найти все файлы с расширением и заменить на сервере

Tags: php

Проблема следующая, на сервер загржужены файлы с некорректным расширением .array. Нужно найти на сервере в папке все файлы .array и заменить на .jpg. Как это делается в php ?

Comment: glob, basename, rename

Answer (score 0):

```html
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/content/products/';
    
    $files1 = scandir($path);

    
    foreach ($files1 as $key => $value) {
        
        if (pathinfo($path.$value)['extension'] == 'array') {
            $old_name = $path.$value;
    
            $new_name = pathinfo($old_name, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . '/' . pathinfo($old_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '.jpg';
            rename($old_name, $new_name);
        }
        
    }
```